# Closing and re-opening a form without closing the application

Tags: c#, winforms, reset

I am trying to reset my main form so that I can reset all text boxes and variables easily. I have added a bool to my Progam.cs to enable the application to stay open while the form is closed and then re-opened. When I try to close it, the on_closing even fires twice. I'm not sure what to do to stop it happening, but I know it's got to be something simple.

Program.cs:

```
static class Program
{
    public static bool KeepRunning { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        KeepRunning = true;
        while (KeepRunning)
        {
            KeepRunning = false;
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }

    }
}
```

Form1:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Program.KeepRunning = true;
        this.Close();
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("You have unsaved work! Save before closing?", "Save?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            MessageBox.Show("saving then closing");
            Application.Exit();
        }

        if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("closing");
            Application.Exit();
        }

        if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Cancel)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            MessageBox.Show("canceling");
        }
    }
```

Comment: @HansPassant, I'd say this is certainly not a duplicate and quite likely to be another duplicate syndrome case. Even if the solution would be the same, these are different questions.

Comment: "Closing a form without closing the application", exact same question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove your `Application.Exit()`. Since you are already in the FormClosing Event Handler, the Application will exit if `Program.KeepRunning` is set to false.

Comment: If I do that and then click no it never closes. It just re-opens after you click no over and over.

Comment: I updated my answer, because i read your question a little bit to fast

Comment: Thanks alot that was it and it makes sense now.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you call Application.Exit(). Since, your form is not closed yet, if you try to close the application, that instruction will try to close the form fist which, in turn, will call the event handler a second time.

Also, I don't think you need Application.Exit() because that's your only form and the application will, therefore, close automatically (at least that's what happened in my VB6 old times!)